# Searching in an array for numbers with each element +1 or -1 of preceding element

Tags: algorithm, search, language-agnostic

An array of integers contains elements such that each element is 1 more or less than its preceding element. Now we are given a number, we need to determine the index of that number's first occurrence in the array.
Need to optimize linear search. Its not homework.

Comment: What is YOUR question? What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: You probably can't do better than linear time.

Comment: Homework or not, you should still try to solve the problem yourself (and show your attempt). (Honestly, for me, whether it's homework or not, or whether *you say* it is or not, plays no role).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My algorithm would be like this:

1. p=0
2. if (A[p] == x) then idx=p and the algorithm is finished else goto next step
3. set p += |x-A[p]|
4. goto 2.

say A[p] > x. Then, since A items increase or decrease by 1, idx is for sure at least (A[p] - x) index away from p. Same principle goes for A[p] < x.

```
int p=0, idx=-1;
while (p<len && p>=0)
   if (A[p]==x)
       idx = p;
   else
       p+= abs(x-A[p]);
```

Time complexity: The worst case would be O(n). I expect the average case to be better than O(n) ( I think it's O(log n) but not sure about it). 
Running time: Definitely better than linear search for all cases.

Comment: Still has linear runtime though, in case linear search was not possible due to runtime complexity

Comment: @NiklasB. Not sure if the average case is also O(n). Even in that case, it will have a better running time comparing to simple linear search.

Comment: Definitely. I just wanted to point out that this is still linear in the worst case.

Comment: Isn't that `(x-A[p])` supposed to be `|x-A[p]|` (i.e. absolute value)?

Comment: Thanks @Dukeling. I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be faster than linear. The following code should be as fast as you can go:

```
int findFirstIndex(int num, int[] array) {
     int i = 0;
     while (i< array.length)
          if (array[i] == num) return i;
          else i += abs(array[i] - num)
     return -1
}
```

But it's still O(array.length) in the worst case. Think for example if you are looking for 1 in an array containing only 0. Then, you can't skip any position.

Answer (score 0):

Start from first position; now consider the difference between the searched number N and first number. if array[0] == N then we finished; otherwise we have to jump of abs(array[0] -N ) positions; now just repeat this until the end of the array.